# Can't get AutoFill to Drag down to last Row

Tags: excel, vba

The workbook I'm working on has 16 Worksheets. Starting with Sheet2 (Report1) before I loop it through the other worksheets.

When I open the Workbook, it opens on Sheet1 (TOC), and I'm trying to run the Macro from here.

On Sheet2, Rows 1-3 is Header data.

-I entered a formula into F4, but I can't seem to get a formula AutoFill down Column F to the last row based on of data based on Column A.  (There can be blank Cells in Column F)

-Then I would like take the formula from F4, copy/paste to K4, and Autofill down Column K as well.

(Now if I'm actually IN Worksheet2, it works??) Do I need to move to each Active Sheet in order to get this to work?

This is what I currently have:

```
Sub Test()

'Turn Off Screen Updates
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = Worksheets("Report1")

'Update $ - % Chg formula
    ws.Range("F4").Formula = "=(E4/(E4-G4))-1"
    ws.Range("F4").NumberFormat = "0.0%"
    Range("F4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("F4:F" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

'Update Units - % Chg Formula
    ws.Range("F4").Copy Range("K4")
    Range("K4").AutoFill Destination:=Range("K4:K" & Range("A" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

'Turn On Screen Updates
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Define your worksheet/s properly, and don't use Autofill, just paste the formula to the range you want. e.g. `Dim ws As Worksheet: Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2")`
`ws.Cells(4, 6).Resize(ws.Cells(ws.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row - 3).Formula = "==(E4/(E4-G4))-1"`

Comment: @GMalc - This string gives me the Run-Time error '1004': Application-defined or object-defined error

Comment: @GMalc - As I'm still learning, changing the "Set ws = Worksheets("Report1")" to "Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet2") is now showing the Error - Run-Time error '9': Subscript out of range.   Why is this?

Comment: This was just an example to show you how to define your workbook and worksheet and use the variable within the code. You need to change the sheet name to your worksheets name. And if the sheet is not in the workbook that contains the code, you need to clarify what workbook you are trying to access.